# How to check if all values in an array are equal

Tags: c#, linq

The following checks if all values in a string array are equal ignoring the case

```
string [] StringArray = new string[]{"xxx","xXx","Xxx"}; 
bool ValuesAreEqual = false;
for(int i= 0;i<StringArray.Length;i++)
{
    if(i>=1)
    {
        ValuesAreEqual = StringArray[0].Equals(StringArray[i],StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if(!ValuesAreEqual)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How could I write this using LINQ?

Comment: Try using the `.All` extension

Comment: I guess `"xxx,xXx,Xxx"` should be `"xxx","xXx","Xxx"`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to know if all are equal [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is efficient and readable:

```
string firstItem = StringArray[0];
bool allEqual = StringArray.Skip(1)
  .All(s => string.Equals(firstItem, s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

`All` breaks also on the first comparison that returns `false`. Note that i've used the static [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent null-reference exceptions on `null` objects.

By the way, your loop is incorrect since you start to compare at index 2 instead of 1 here:

```
if(i > 1 ) // indices are zero based
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But if x=z and x=y then z=y

Comment: @FPGA: sorry, i don't follow.

Comment: loop is correct, it is `>=` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter i meant if all items items are equal to the first item then all items are equal

Comment: @FPGA: yes, that's the similar way than in my LINQ approach using `Enumerable.All` where i'm comparing all with the first string. However, your loop is still incorrect ;) **Edit** Now you've corrected it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the loop was incorrect but i fixed it in the first minute ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] StringArray = new string[] {"xxx,xXx,Xxx"};
bool areEqual = StringArray.Select(s => s.ToLower()).Distinct().Count()==1;

bool areEqual = StringArray.GroupBy(s => s.ToLower()).Count() == 1;
```

just to be original here:)

Comment: Maybe your code is missing something? :-)

Comment: yeah, `Distinct()` ;) Thanks man

Answer (score 3):

```
 string[] StringArray = new string[] { "xxx","xXx","Xxx" };

 var item = StringArray.FirstOrDefault();
 bool match = StringArray.Skip(1).All(i => i.ToLower() == item.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool areEqual = stringArray.Any()
                  ? stringArray.All(str => str.Equals(stringArray[0], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                  : true;
```

Comment: Two nitpicks: 1.) throws a `NullReferenceException` if the array contains nulls, 2.) is a little bit less efficient than storing the first string in a variable since everytime needs to be checked if `0` is a valid index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, but your answer already addresses those issues. If I were to fix my answer, it would look like I was copying yours :) By the way, yours will also throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the array has 0 length.